# specify X11 or WM property (xprop) when lauching application

Tags: x11, gnome, window-manager

I have a x11 gui application running on GNOME (Fedora 24), which by default launches using the light GTK theme.

I would like to make it use the dark GTK theme variant, and found that after launching the window, one could do the following to change the theme variant:

```
$ xprop -f _GTK_THEME_VARIANT 8u -set _GTK_THEME_VARIANT "dark"
```

So, my question is, how to specify this setting at launch time, similar to this:

```
$ some_magic my_x11_app  # launch as dark theme
```

? Thank you!

Comment: What is the app?

Comment: It's a variant of xterm,  named xgterm